# Angular 4 Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular

I know that there is already questions like this that has answers to it, but i tried the most common solutions and i have been unsuccessful.

I'm cloning an angular 4 project from github and i do an `npm install` and i get this error when i run `ng serve`.

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>       at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
>       at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
>       at BuildCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:180:32)
>       at BuildCommand. (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:47:25)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
>       at BuildCommand.initialize (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:46:16)
>       at Object. (/Users/poweruser/Applications/nodework/angular4-file-upload/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:87:23)

My node version is

`v8.11.2`

My angular version is

Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.1.3

Any suggestions on what i should do ?

Comment: what version of angular cli do you have installed globally?

Comment: seems like you have 6 installed going by the fact it's looking for 'angular.json' and not 'angular-cli.json'

Comment: my bad...just saw your versions

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading your project version of angular-cli to a version that's compatible with ng4...or upgrade the ng4 app to ng6